# Webhook only firing when I log in

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, craft4, plugin-webhooks

I've set up a Webhook in Craft 4 that triggers a Zap.
The Sender class is craft\commerce\elements\Subscription and the event name is afterSave.
When the trigger action happens (a user subscription), the Webhook does not fire until I log in to the Craft CP, even if I wait a couple of hours. It is listed as status "pending", then when I refresh the page, it's listed as status 200, and the Zap is activated and works fine.

How can I make it fire automatically? (I'm assuming that is the intended behaviour)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened to me also.

I think this only happens when you are in Dev mode.

Once in production the queues just worked.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I had to set DEV_MODE=false and CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT=production

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to setup a cron job, daemon, or other solution as all versions of Craft CMS can only fire the queue when the admin panel is logged into (HTTP). Please check out:

https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/queue.html#queue-runners

and this handy article by NYStudio107

https://nystudio107.com/blog/robust-queue-job-handling-in-craft-cms

Comment: Thank you I'll try this.